# global keyword defined inside of a function is not updating my variable, but why?

Tags: python, global, keyword

Why is the output of func3 still 'Hello' and isn't 'New Message'? Since func2 is told to change the value of global variable 'update' to the argument passed into func1? I am confused.

```
update = 'Hello'

def func1(message):
    func2(message)

def func2(message):
    global update
    update = message
    func3()

def func3(update = update):
    print(update)
    
    
    
func1('New Message')
```

Comment: Because the default value is evaluated *once* when the function is defined, it isn't re-evaluated every time it is called. The variable is indeed updated by `func2`.

Comment: So when func1 is called the value of variable "update" is evaluated and despite of func2 assigning a new value to it func3 does not notified of the change.

Comment: The default values are evaluated at the point of function definition in the defining scope. So `def func3(update=update):` is same as `def func3(update='Hello'):`

Comment: Would you be able to suggest a way please to re-evaluate the value of "update" after func2 is called?

Comment: Use a container class as the default value i.e. `['hello']` & update it with `update[0] = val`. But it's hacky at best.

Comment: @LucasSchwartz "So when func1 is called the value of variable "update" is evaluated and..." **no**. When `func1` is called, the *variable* is not evaluated at all.

Comment: Or, use two different variable names, and something like `def func3(x=None):` then `if x is None: x = update`

Comment: But *in general* you shouldn't rely on mutable global state like this

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok. now I get it. You meant that the "**default value**" is evaluated which is provided to func3, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call func3 without argument, it evaluates func3 with the default value. And the default value is "Hello".
So you need to call func3 with the new value of update like that:

```
def func2(message):
    global update
    update = message
    func3(update)
```